# Anyway to convert Business Account into person account

Tags: person-accounts

I'm just starting out and was wondering if there is anyway to convert Business Account into Personal Account in Salesforce? I have been searching for a way but all I can find is ways to turn a Personal into a Business Account.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h1K3AAI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the Account's RecordTypeId field to the Person Account Record Type Id. Keep in mind that you are only allowed to specify the RecordTypeId field when converting the account, and only one Contact must be associated the Account when converting. See also [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004176) for additional limitations.

> 1. Manipulate the data such that the following conditions are met:
>
> a. For each intended Person Account, one (and only one) Contact record
>   exists under the Account record.
>
> b. The Account and Contact have the same record owner.
>
> c. The Account and Contact have the same currency values (if
>   applicable).
>
> d. The Parent Account field on the Account and the Reports To field of
>   the Contact are both blank.
>
> e. The Account is not set as the Parent Account of any other Account
>   records.
>
> f. The Contact is not set as the Reports To of any other Contact
>   records.
>
> g. The Account and Contact have not been enabled as Partner/Customer
>   for Portal/Community.
>
> 2. Using the data migration tool of your choice (i.e. something like the Data Loader), change the record type of the target Account to the
>      desired Person Account record type. The detailed steps are listed
>      here. *Please note that this cannot be done with Workbench, as it will
>      return the error: "Cannot Specify Any Additional Fields When Marrying
>      Or Separating A Person-Account INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE"

Comment: Is there an updated link for the help topic?

Comment: Hey there fox - can this be done (or similar) via apex?  I am getting that error when I try to set the ID.  It lets me set the RecordType child object and perform the update, but it doesn't convert it nor actually save the new record type. :/

Comment: @Shane Yes, it can be done in Apex (I've done it myself). I'd suggest a new question with the relevant code, we'll be glad to take a peek at it!

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks.  Here it is: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285438/problem-converting-from-business-to-person-account-in-apex