# Unable to convert portal contacts to person accounts

Tags: apex, person-accounts

We have about 350,000 portal users who are setup as contacts in Salesforce that we would like to convert to person accounts.

Here are the steps that worked well for non-portal users, but fail for portal users:

1. Create a new business account for each of those contacts.
2. Update the AccountId for Contacts with corresponding business account
   created above.
3. *Change the record type for each account to person
   account.* --> **This step throws below exception for portal users.**

> INVALID_PERSON_ACCOUNT_OPERATION, account cannot be converted to
>   person-account: []

Unfortunately the exception doesn't tell why it failed. Wondering if there a workaround to this? I looked at [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144134/anyway-to-convert-business-account-into-person-account) and [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000094GuIAI) but they seem to address a standard contact but not a *portal* contact. And again, we got it to work for standard contacts.

Comment: is it old portal or communities?

Comment: portal and not a community.

Comment: Is it partner portal or customer portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the limitation of Person Account for Portals.

> Person accounts can't be enabled as users for partner communities and
>   portals because partners represent companies, not individuals.

Also,

> You can’t merge person accounts that are enabled to use portal or
>   community users.

So when you try to do this, it will fail as partner portal user should always be contacts and not person accounts.

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person_behavior.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_person_accounts_limitation.htm&type=5#networks_person_accounts_limitation

Comment: Are we able to disable portal for customers, convert to person accounts and then enable portal back? Not worried about downtime, but I hope this doesn't send any email communication to customers by itself (like a welcome email or something after disable/enable).

Comment: Try on sandbox first to see the effects, on another note the contact will still have associated USER login so even if you disable them the user will be there so it wont allow you to do it.